# IntelliJ Kotlin variable suggestion

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

How to make IntelliJ show variable name suggestions like i Java?

Java:
[image]

Now I get something like this:
[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug

Comment: I have tested on Android Studio (Windows and Mac) and IntelliJ (Windows).

Comment: Have you tested in IntelliJ 2020.1?

Comment: IntelliJ 2020.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is not implemented for the Kotlin plugin. Please watch the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39230 for updates.